# Focus not going back to the other qml from popup dialog qml

Tags: qt, qml

From ListView qml i selected a item and the popup dialog(qml) is opened.

Initiallially focus is not coming , so i forced focus using 
listview.currentItem.forceActiveFocus() // inside popup qml

but after closing the dialog focus is not regaining back to the ListView  qml selected item.

```
onButtonAction: {
    switch (action) {
    case ButtonActions.PRESSED:

        container.ListView.view.currentIndex = index;
        itemloader.item.forceActiveFocus();
        break;
    }
}
```

this is the segment im using to regain focus on clicking the button.

After dialog gets focus,  and closing the dialog, **the cursor(focus) was staying on the popup layer and not returning to the base layer.**

> Component.onCompleted: {
>           console.log("___________ Alert onCompleted(), focus: " + focus
>            + " activeFocus: " + activeFocus)
>               accept_button.forceActiveFocus();
>               return;
>       }

output is coming

Focus: true, ActiveFocus: false

so always active focus is coming false , so accept_button.forceActiveFocus() works only on mouse interaction onButtonAction()

my Complete Code

```
FocusScope
{
    signal buttonAction(int index, int action)

    property int itemWidth: 200
    property int itemHeight: 70

    id: disclaimer_view
    anchors.fill: parent
    focus: true
ButtonText
    {
        id: accept_button
        objectName: "accept_button"

        //: Accept button to close disclaimer
        //# REQ HMI_10
        text: qsTranslate("", "Accept")+ Retranslate.whenLocaleOrLangChanges

        type: "regular"
        fontSize: 36
        fontBold: true
        width: disclaimer_view.itemWidth
        height: disclaimer_view.itemHeight
        onButtonAction: disclaimer_view.buttonAction(0, action)
        anchors.bottom: warning_background.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 10
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("___________Harley Disclaimer onCompleted(), focus: " + focus
         + " activeFocus: " + activeFocus)
            accept_button.forceActiveFocus();
            return;
    }


}
```

Comment: Which version of controls are you using (what's the import)? Also, if you add `onActiveFocusItemChanged: print(activeFocusItem)` to the window, what does it print? Also, a minimal, complete example would get you answers much quicker.

Comment: thanks mitch . i will upload the complete details in few minutes .

Comment: @mitch: i updated my code sample . i observed that focus is getting true but activeFocus is always coming false. so the forceActiveFocus also failing.

Comment: @mitch onActiveFocusItemChanged is not  a property for FocusScope it is coming . but i tried onActiveFocusChanged , it returns false.

Comment: That's not a complete example, though. A complete QML example would look something like this: https://gist.github.com/mitchcurtis/3fbaafb8ed1717fb76bc#file-main-qml Are you not using a Window as your top-level item? A complete example would also show us which imports you are using, which you haven't told us yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, there the solution was to close the popup with `popup.close()`, instead of any other means.